# Child nodes using hierarchical query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out all child nodes in Mysql DB. I searched the same on net got the solution but it doesn't worked for me. i did this in oracle using connnect by prior but i need this in mysql. Please help me.
Here is data of my tale membertable.
mysql> select * from membertable;

```
+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| memberid | membername | parentId | leg   |
+----------+------------+----------+-------+
|      101 | abc        |     NULL | NULL  |
|      102 | def        |      101 | Left  |
|      103 | jkl        |      101 | Right |
|      104 | ghi        |      102 | Left  |
|      105 | mno        |      102 | Right |
|      106 | pqr        |      103 | Left  |
|      107 | stu        |      103 | Right |
+----------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Suppose I pass memberid = 102, i am expecting data like this.

```
+----------+------------+----------+-------+
|      102 | def        |      101 | Left  |
|      104 | ghi        |      102 | Left  |
|      105 | mno        |      102 | Right |
|      106 | pqr        |      103 | Left  |
|      107 | stu        |      103 | Right | 
+----------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Please do needfull....

Comment: why you expect the last two rows? I don't understand

Comment: Hi Enrique, Thanks for the response and sorry for confusion I am not expecting last two rows. here is correct expected output. for membered = 102                                                                                                         +----------+------------+----------+-------+
|      102 | def        |      101 | Left  |
|      104 | ghi        |      102 | Left  |
|      105 | mno        |      102 | Right